# Ubuntu vsftpd hide other folder and disable possibility to browse them

Tags: permissions, chroot, vsftpd, active-directory, filezilla

I'm relatively new to Linux. I am creating an SFTP server using vsftpd on ubuntu 20. I'm authenticating users with Active directory.
The problem I have, is that even though the user land in their home directory, they can just go up in FileZilla for example and browse and even download other folders.
Is there a way to hide other folders outside of the user home folder and disable the possibility to browse or download them?
I don't actually need the users to have permissions outside of their own folder.
Here's is my vsftpd.conf:

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES

write_enable=YES

local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES

xferlog_enable=YES

connect_from_port_20=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES
ascii_download_enable=NO

ftpd_banner=Welcome to your FTP server

chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES

#ls_recurse_enable=YES

secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

pam_service_name=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
session_support=YES
pasv_enable=YES
local_max_rate=0
idle_session_timeout=600
data_connection_timeout=120
seccomp_sandbox=NO

force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
debug_ssl=YES

force_dot_files=NO

hide_ids=YES

max_per_ip=2

local_root=/home/vftp/$USER
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
pasv_min_port=9900
pasv_max_port=9950
```

Is there any way to do this? hide all other folders and maybe disable the ability to browse and download as well.
Any help would be highly appreciated guys. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: you chroot_list_enable=yes, did you make the list? You do NOT choot_local_user=yes (though it should work, but the logic is worse because you enabled a list)..... chroot_local_user=NO, then use the list to indicate the users that should be chrooted. try that first to start with. It sounds like they aren't actually chrooted? https://linux.die.net/man/5/vsftpd.conf There are download options listed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I am getting the users directly from an Active Directory, so I don't want to create a manual list. However I did tested with having a list for certain users. The user does land in their home folder, but if they press up, they can easily navigate through other users folders, as well as system folders. They can't create or change files, but they can download those file. Is there a way to get around this at all?

Comment: 2 things.... 1.) how exactly or what are the clients using to log in? 2) If possible, I still would try testing with the more simplistic configuration with the list, until I get it to deny the users' access. With the behavior of the options being a little counter-intuitive it kind of makes it harder to troubleshoot, especially when you have to get clarification... for example, are you saying you tested chroot_local_USER=NO, chroot_list_enable=YES, and chroot_list_file= a designated list of "certain users" and it didnt work? ...also are you restarting the vsftpd service after every change?

Comment: 1) I am testing from Win 10, using Filezilla SFTP. 2) Yes I changed chroot_local_USER=NO, added specific users to the list and tested. 3) Yeah I restart vsftpd after every change. Its very strange. The user does land within their user folder located in the home folder, but with a simple click up, they can easily browse the whole system.  Thanks again for taking the time to help!

Comment: I believe if you ftp in, you will find that it works...Try that.......  sftp is ssh....you need to config your chroot jails in ssh if you want to use sftp. I believe you would have to configure /etc/ssh/sshd_config under the Match user section... web search "chroot jails sftp"

Comment: Thank you for all the help! It did not work still. I started with a fresh system, cause I couldn't locate the issue. and now it seems to work for local users. i.e users within the system itself. For some reason now however, users coming from my AD can not even login to the FTP server. I always get a "530 Login incorrect" error.